# Are there any general exploring guides for Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm looking for a guide that tells you about the lay of the land, different abilities and powers, as well as some basic tips on playing well. I don't want a quest walkthrough, just something that gauges the scope and gameplay of Skyrim. Any help is welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whats the point of exploring if you know everything before you are there?

Comment: I've voted to close this because I really don't think there can be one definitive answer.  If you have more specific questions, though, definitely ask them!

Comment: The [Unofficial Elder Scrolls Pages wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Skyrim)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I personally wouldn't recommend it.... the best thing I know of this type other than the printed guide is the skyrim wiki : http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Skyrim

(The reason I don't recommend it is you'll spoil a lot of the game for yourself by using something like this. It's far more fun to do it the other way around and refer to the guide if you get stuck.)

Comment: There's also [The Ultimate Elder Scrolls Pages](http://www.uesp.net/)

Comment: @lszi I always found it lacking personally.

Comment: @djsmiley2k I guess it's personal taste, as I've always found it the other way around.